# Docker compose up problem in fresh win10 machine

Tags: django, windows, docker-compose, containers

I have problem in run command:

`docker compose up -d`

`failed to solve: archive/tar: unknown file mode ?rwxr-xr-x`

on win 10 machine, docker version is 4.25.2

perhaps, when I run the command:

`docker build --no-cache --rm=false .`

it run successfully without errors !

P.S: I have include image of the error

and this is my docker-compose.yml for further assistance, and DockerFile

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    # the application's web service (container) will use an image based on our Dockerfile
    build: .
    # map the internal port 80 to port 8000 on the host
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    # map the host directory to app (which allows us to see and edit files inside the container)
    volumes:
      - ".:/app:rw"
      - "./data:/data:rw"
    # the default command to run whenever the container is launched
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    # the URL 'postgres' or 'mysql' will point to the application's db service
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
      - search
    env_file: .env-local

  db:
    # Select one of the following db configurations for the database
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --max_allowed_packet=32505856 --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci
    ports:
      - "3360:3306"  # allow your local dev env to connect to the db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "nnuh"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app:rw"
      - "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - default

  cache:
    image: memcached:alpine

  search:
    image: elasticsearch:5.6-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./data/search/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
```

DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install Dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        gcc \
        gettext \
        curl \
        --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD uwsgi --http=0.0.0.0:80 --module=backend.wsgi
```

I have tried removing all containers by
docker system prune -a

I have tried check all my settings for docker on windows

I have tried install public containers and it worked successfully

this docker settings was running previously without problems, but I obliged to formatted my machine today; so maybe this affect the docker settings.

[error in console while running docker compose up -d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PowWe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is fixed
**I have only delete the `data` folder inside my project directory !**

then `docker compose up -d --build` run like a charm

maybe this question will help other facing the same problem.